# JSON.parse error, please tell what is wrong with it?

Tags: ajax, json

After I tried this code, i got this error from firebug: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data.

Since I have a little knowledge of json, I could not figure it out myself. Could you please have a look at my code and please tell me where the error should be from? Please dont put it on hold again.

Here is my ajax code:

```
function sortSubcat(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
 document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML="";
 return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('subcat');
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        var idx = i+1;
        selectElement.options[idx] = new Option(response[idx].value, response[idx].name, false, false);
     }   
 }
}

 xmlhttp.open("GET","/member/sortsubcat.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php
require_once("../configs/dbconnect.php");
if (!empty($_GET['q'])){
 $q = basename($_GET['q']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE maincat=:q";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':q', $q);
$result->execute();
echo "<option value=''>Please select a sub category</option>";
$returned_string = '[';
foreach($result as $row)
{
//echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";
 $returned_string .= '{"name" : "'. $row['name']. '", "value" : "'. $row['name']. '"},';
}
 $returned_string = substr($returned_string, 0, -1); //remove trailing ','
 $returned_string .= ']';
 header("Content-type: application/json");
 echo $returned_string;
 exit;
}
else{
  echo "<option value=''>Please select a sub category</option>";
 }
 $conn=null;
 ?>
```

Here is response from ajax:

```
[{"name" : "sub1", "value" : "sub1"},{"name" : "sub2", "value" : "Sub2"}]
```

Comment: Why are you creating a JSON string by hand in your PHP code when PHP has a perfectly good `json_encode()` function???

Comment: My original code is: //echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>"; How can i use json_encode() function for this case? Please explain?

Comment: I've posted an answer to clarify. But you should really look up the PHP manual page for `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but if the AJAX response you posted

```
<option value=''>Please select a sub category</option>[{"name" : "sub1", "value" : "sub1"},{"name" : "sub2", "value" : "Sub2"}]
```

is supposed to be JSON, the problem is that the response *isn't* JSON. The first part is HTML, the second part is JSON. If your code is expecting JSON, it will not accept an HTML / JSON mix.

Comment: after i get rid of the html part, then i got this error: TypeError: response[idx] is undefined??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're outputting JSON, then you can't also output HTML, so you need to drop the bits where you're echoing the `<option>` tags.

Secondly, if you're outputting JSON, you really should use PHP's built-in `json_encode()` function rather than building the JSON string yourself.

Here's your code with the above changes made:

```
<?php
require_once("../configs/dbconnect.php");
$output = [];
if (empty($_GET['q'])){
    $q = basename($_GET['q']);
    $sql="SELECT name as name, name as value FROM subcat WHERE maincat=:q";
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':q', $q);
    $result->execute();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```